# Deselecting a ttk::checkbutton

Tags: checkbox, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have defined multiple ttk::checkbutton in a table. There requires a single Master checkbutton which will select or deselect all other checkbuttons at once. We can also select single checkbutton.

Now the problem is, I can select the child checkbuttons But I can not deselect them through code. I know I can deselect them all with a variable but I dont want to do that.Because all checkbuttons will then be linked. what to do.

Is Linking all checkbuttons with with different variables and then reseting them is the only option ?

Select code which works fine:

```
$childCheck state selected
```

the deselect code I have tried but failed:

```
$childCheck state deselected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got the answer. :)
Instead of deselected use !selected in state.

```
$childCheck state !selected
```

Comment: you then might want to accept this very answer of yours, otherwise others will see it as unsolved.